# jQuery changes inner text directly inside and not of inner element

Tags: jquery

My code:

```
<script>

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'location': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
    success: function(listings) {
        jQuery("div[id='xxxxxxx']").each(function(index) {
            jQuery(this).contents()[0].data = xxxxxxxxxx[index].name;
        });
    }});

</script>
```

Runs fine on `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

except that it inserts inner text in selected DIV elements. My page has `<h2>` tag whose inner text has to be changed and not DIV's inner text. What can I do?

Like:

```
<div id='xxxxxxxxxxxx>
 <h2>New text</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` should be unique. And why not use `.text()`?

Comment: .text() replaces all outer html. I only need to change inner text of h2 of all selected div. I have to somehow select h2 of the selected div in $.each

Comment: h2 h3 is dynamic right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you have many `div` with the same id `clinic_name`. It's not good because `id` should be unique, you can use `class` instead.

If you want to change text of the `h2` inside the div, you can use this selector `div.clinic_name h2:first-child`(here I use `class` instead of `id`).

Example:

```
jQuery("div.clinic_name h2:first-child").each(function(index) {
  jQuery(this).text(listings[index].name);
});
```

Or if `h2` is not the first child:

```
jQuery("div.clinic_name").each(function(index) {
  jQuery(this).find("h2").text(listings[index].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need find child first you can use this

```
jQuery(this).find(':first-child').text(listings[index].name);
//this = div.clinic_name
```

First child can be get any element inside or you use these...

- `.find(':first-child')` if you need find first of inside
- `.find(':last-child')` if you need find last of inside
- `.find(':eq(3)')` if you need find 3rd item of inside
- `.find('selector')` if you need find sepecific tag class id

For call element you can use

- tag with id `tag#id` instead `tag[id="id"]`

  > It will warn in your editor as **duplicate id**
- if it has many you need to use `<tag class="class"><tag class="class">`.
  So you can use many as you can

```js
jQuery("input#return_dat").on("click", function() {
  var listings = [{
    "name": "arr1"
  }, {
    "name": "arr2"
  }, {
    "name": "arr3"
  }, {
    "name": "arr4"
  }, {
    "name": "arr5"
  }, {
    "name": "arr6"
  }];
  jQuery("div.clinic_name").each(function(index) {
    jQuery(this).find(':first-child').text(listings[index].name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='clinic_name'>
  <h1>xxx</h1>
</div>
<div class='clinic_name'>
  <h2>xxx</h2>
</div>
<div class='clinic_name'>
  <h3>xxx</h3>
</div>
<div class='clinic_name'>
  <h4>xxx</h4>
</div>
<div class='clinic_name'>
  <h5>xxx</h5>
</div>
<div class='clinic_name'>
  <h6>xxx</h6>
</div>
<input id="return_dat" type="button" value="click">
```